# basic twig, 'updating' template

Tags: php, twig

I'm new to php and twig so please don't get upset if these questions sound stupid ;)

I'm tying out twig and buttons. What I want to do: 
A variable $num is 1, and is shown in the template {{ num }}, like this:

**1 

[change value]**

The user clicks a button (named "change value") to add 1 to $num (so now, $num is 2). The template should now update and show a "2", like this:

**2

[change value]**

The user clicks again and its 3 and so on...

What happens in my application is:
User clicks button, the whole index.html is added to the first one, so now it shows:

**1

[change value]

2

[change value]**

instead of just:

**2

[change value]**

Now after this, if the user clicks the button again, nothing happens.

How can I "update" the variable in the template? And why can I only click the button once?

Heres my html code:

```
<html>
<body>

<p> {{ tempOne }} </p>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="change value"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and my php:

```
<?php

$twig = require_once('bootstrap.php');
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password =  '';
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mydb", $username, $password);
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');

$num = 1;
echo $template->render(array('tempOne' => $num));

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $num = $num + 1;
    echo $template->render(array('tempOne' => $num));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your php code to following:

```
<?php

$twig = require_once('bootstrap.php');
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password =  '';
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mydb", $username, $password);
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $num = $_POST['num'] + 1;
    echo $template->render(array('tempOne' => $num));
} else {
    $num = 1;
    echo $template->render(array('tempOne' => $num));
}
```

And HTML to :

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="num" value="{{tempOne}}"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="change value"/>
</form>
```

Comment: now nothing happens when I click the button. EDIT: NEVERMIND it works, I deleted the <p> tag by accident. Thank you! What exactly does the "hidden" input tag do?

Comment: As its name, it is a hidden text field which contains current value of your variable and send through POST while submitting the form. So you always add +1 to the current value.

Comment: so $num gets its value from the html hidden input tag and then adds 1? Why does it not work the other way? I don't understand why in my code twig->render adds the entire html content to the old content. Why does this not happen in your code? :)

Comment: if you check your code, you were having 2 echo which was causing this issue. In my code it will echo once whether its in if or in else. Also you were assigning $num = 1; so everytime when you submit form $num is 1 and adds 1 so the values remains 1 and 2.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!